# MySQL update calculation wrong for division

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a mysql table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `entries` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `domain_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `presentation_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `total_score` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `times_played` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `avg_score` float(4,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=206 ;
```

I am updating data with PHP
But the query calculating wrong for 'avg_score' while updating. Lets say, the entire row looks like this:

```
id   domain_name   presentation_name  total_score  times_played   avg_score
1    test.com      test               30           3              10.00
```

But when I run this update query with new data:

```
$score = 6;
$query = "UPDATE `entries` 
                        SET 
                            total_score = (total_score + $score), 
                            times_played = (times_played + 1), 
                            avg_score = ( (total_score + $score) / (times_played + 1) ) 
                    WHERE id = '1'";
```

it becomes like this:

```
id   domain_name   presentation_name  total_score  times_played   avg_score
1    test.com      test               36           4              8.40
```

You can see the 'avg_score' is wrong (should be 9.00). I have tried same query in phpmyadmin and got same wrong calculation. Can't really find what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Try converting your `avg_score` field to a `DECIMAL(4,2)` field. Floats can be tricky when doing calculations like this.

Comment: No FLOAT is not the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html):

> The second assignment in the following statement sets col2 to the
>   current (updated) col1 value, not the original col1 value. The result
>   is that col1 and col2 have the same value. **This behavior differs from
>   standard SQL**.
>
> ```
> UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 1, col2 = col1;
> ```

So you can omit the + score and + 1 when you update the average:

```
UPDATE `entries` SET 
    total_score  = total_score  + $score, 
    times_played = times_played + 1, 
    avg_score    = total_score / times_played
WHERE id = '1'
```

Answer (score 2):

See

```
total_score = (total_score + $score),
```

36 = 30 + 6

```
times_played = (times_played + 1),
```

4 = 3 + 1

then you do

```
avg_score = ( (total_score + $score) / (times_played + 1) )
```

8.4 = (36 + 6) / 5

Is correct!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your first two columns get updated and the updated values are used when updating the third column, note that `8.4 = (36 + 6) / (4 + 1)`

So you don't need the `+1` and `+  $score` for your third column.

Although you really should not store duplicate data in your database as that can only lead to problems like this.

Just calculate the average when you need it, either in php or mysql.

Answer (score 1):

try:
changing the sequence (preferred approach)

```
                    SET 
                        avg_score = ( (total_score + $score) / (times_played + 1) ) ,
                        total_score = (total_score + $score), 
                        times_played = (times_played + 1)
```

or:

```
                    SET 
                        total_score = (total_score + $score), 
                        times_played = (times_played + 1), 
                        avg_score = ( (total_score) / (times_played) )
```

You are referencing fields already being adjusted in subsequent calculations but making the assumption they have remain unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the updates are being done incrementally.

That is, Total score goes to 36, times played to 4, and then the calculation for avg_score is done (36 + 6, 4  + 1) = 42/5 = 8.4

Try updating avg_score in another sentence.

No clue what is doing that though.

Answer (score 0):

**Change:**

```
$score = 6;
$query = "UPDATE `entries` 
                        SET 
                            total_score = (total_score + $score), 
                            times_played = (times_played + 1), 
                            avg_score = ( (total_score + $score) / (times_played + 1) ) 
                    WHERE id = '1'";
```

**To:**

```
  $score = 6;
    $query = "UPDATE `entries` 
                            SET 
                                total_score = (total_score + $score), 
                                times_played = (times_played + 1), 
                                avg_score = (total_score /times_played ) 
                        WHERE id = '1'";
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55287/1/0)